# Mocking DataSource for JdbcTemplate with Mockito

Tags: java, mocking, datasource, mockito, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to test a class in a Spring project. I would like to make as many changes as possible in the test class vs. the dao class so that I don't have to retest all sorts things because of a change.

The class I'm working with has a `JdbcTemplate template` class variable that is instantiated by the following:

```
setJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

The method I would like to test makes a `template.query(<code>)` to run a defined SQL query and return the results to a list.

I created the following in my test case, but I'm not sure how to put it into use. Can I make the following code return a certain list of Strings using Mockito?

```
DataSource mockedDataSrc = Mockito.mock(DataSource.class);
customerClassDao.setJdbcTemplate(mockedDataSrc);
```

Can I somehow use the `when` or another command to set what I want to be returned to the JdbcTemplate's `.query` call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this because you don't have control over the `JdbcTemplate` implementation. You should dependency inject the `JdbcTemplate` and then mock the `JdbcTemplate` instead.

This difficulty is pointing out a problem with your code.  Your code depends on the concrete instance of `JdbcTemplate`.  It would be less coupled if you used Dependency Injection on it instead.

---

Since you don't want to modify your system under test, you can do this:

Change the `template` field so it's package protected (ie: remove the private keyword). Then, I'd set it to be a mock(JdbcTemplate.class) after you instantiate the class you're testing. Now you'll be able to use when and verify on the JdbcTemplate directly like you wanted originally.

So the class you're testing will look like this:

```
public class SystemUnderTest {

JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

}
```

And your test will do this:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    SystemUnderTest sut = new SystemUnderTest();
    sut.jdbcTemplate = mock(JdbcTemplate.class);                
}

// ...
```

Comment: The data source is injected via Spring through the applicationContext.xml. I'm not sure why they chose just to inject the datasource instead of the jdbcTemplate, but I was trying to be able to test my method that I wrote without having to change/refactor too much else of the code. As my change really only affects 1 SQL call in 1 method.

Comment: Does your test crash if you mock the dataSource and pass it in right now?  If not, there's some things you can do, but I need to know that first.

Comment: It does not crash, it just says successful. I just didn't where to go from here, I'm very new to Mockito/jUnit. I've been Googling a few hours and still quite haven't figured out where to go besides the two lines I showed above.

Comment: Thanks, that got me headed in the right direction. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If you're testing a DAO it makes no sense at all to mock the data source.  What are you testing?  You need to make a DAO that interacts with the database.

Once you have that working, you're free to mock the interface-based DAO when testing services that use it.  You've already tested the DAO; there's no reason to redo it when testing the services.

I'd say you're off-track if you're mocking the data source when testing the DAO.

Comment: It could be useful to test a RowMapper or some other code in the DAO that takes the resultset and builds something other than a vanilla query response.

Comment: If the DAO works you can either mock the ResultSet OR include the RowMapper in the DAO tests.