# Simulate JDBC data source

Tags: java, json, jdbc

I am attempting to simulate a JDBC 3 compliant data source.

I have a legacy java application that only accepts JDBC data sources and cannot be changed. I would like it to be able to use data from a provided JSON file and convert it into some type of source that can be connected to using JDBC. It is impossible to change or access the legacy java application source code, and the application requires data to be retrieved through a JDBC connection.

Is this possible?

At the moment the only solution I can think of is to import the JSON file into a SQL database and then connect to that. I would like to avoid this because the JSON file is originally generated from a database and provided through a web service. I cannot connect to the original database.

Comment: May be able to use a mock test library. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668234/mocking-datasource-for-jdbctemplate-with-mockito

Comment: Load it to local file database like H2 and access it using JDBC as usual