# HikariCP - how to configure a mock datasource for unit tests

Tags: java, spring, hikaricp

I have some sort of integration test that starts my service but do not do actual DB calls.

I am getting such exceptions:

```
[      main] 11:04:47,368 ERROR HikariPool:566 - HikariPool-1 - 
Exception during pool initialization.
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Which is ok for my test (it is passing). However, I would like not to have that error in the log, it makes developers confuse when the test fails.
I am using spring configuration. Is there some kind of mock datasource that I can configure?

Comment: do you mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668234/mocking-datasource-for-jdbctemplate-with-mockito?

Comment: similar, but for hikaricp instead of spring jdbc

Answer (score 0):

I am using kotlin, spring boot,  and io.mockk:mockk for this.
In your integration test, you specify context configuration by placing this at the top

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [DBConfiguration::class])
```

Where the class described above is where your mocked DB connection is.

Your `DBConfiguration` class would look like this

```
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.mockk
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary
import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData

/**
 * Custom configuration class used for testing and disables database connection and initial connection verification
 */
class DBConfiguration {
    @Primary
    @Bean
    fun hikariDataSource(): HikariDataSource {
        val connection: Connection = mockk()
        val databaseMetadata: DatabaseMetaData = mockk()
        val hikariDataSource: HikariDataSource = mockk()
        hikariDataSource
        every { hikariDataSource.connection }.returns(connection)
        every { hikariDataSource.connectionTestQuery }.returns("yeet")
        every { hikariDataSource.metricRegistry }.returns(Any())
        every { hikariDataSource.maximumPoolSize }.returns(2)
        every { hikariDataSource.minimumIdle }.returns(2)
        every { connection.metaData }.returns(databaseMetadata)
        return hikariDataSource
    }
}
```